# Cannot add new products or they get mixed up with updated ones, no error

Tags: php, products, script

I have written a simple script that downloads an XML with product info from a wholesale parse it and save new products or updates exiting ones. It has been working for a few months, but now it's getting really strange. It updates existing products correctly, but it doesn't add a new ones (no error at all) or it overwrites an existing product with the new ones data. I've been trying to find any clue, to debug I output almost any valuable info, but it just won't work.

This is my script:

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();
require_once('Kategorie.php');
$kat = new Kategorie();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://services.azymut.pl/oferta/servlet/?mode=getdb&id=XX&p=XX") or die("Error: Cannot create object ksiazki");
//$xml=simplexml_load_file("testdb.xml");

$ksiazki = array();
$dostepnosc = array();
$ceny = array();

echo count($xml->books->book)." książek pobrano.<br>";

if (count($xml->books->book) > 0)
{
    foreach ($xml->books->book as $book)
    {
        if ($book->attributes()->dzial == "KC")
        {
            if ($kat->isIndexHistoric((string)$book->attributes()->indeks))
            {
                array_push($ksiazki, $book);

                //pobieranie obrazow
                $url = "http://services.azymut.pl/oferta/servlet/?mode=getImg&indeks=".$book->attributes()->indeks."&id=XX&p=XX";
                $path = dirname(__FILE__)."/media/books/".$book->attributes()->indeks.".jpeg";
                $urlFile = "/media/books/".$book->attributes()->indeks.".jpeg";
                try
                {
                    $curl = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    $img = curl_exec($curl);
                    curl_close($curl);
                    $data = imagecreatefromstring($img);
                    if (isset($data))
                    {
                        imagejpeg($data,$path);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception $e)
                {
                    echo "MagentoError: ".$e->getMessage();
                    Mage::log($e->getMessage());
                }

                echo $book->attributes()->indeks.": ".(file_exists($path) ? "Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/".$book->attributes()->indeks.".jpeg)<br>" : "Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.<br>");
            }
        }
    }

    $transakcja = $xml->attributes()->transactionId;
    echo "Transakcja ".$xml->attributes()->transactionId."<br>";

    $xml2 = simplexml_load_file("http://services.azymut.pl/oferta/servlet/?mode=getAvail&id=XX&p=XX") or die("Error: Cannot create object dostepnosc");

    foreach ($xml2->book as $book)
    {
        $index = (string)$book->attributes()->indeks;
        $dostepnosc[$index] = intval($book->attributes()->p);
    }

    echo "Pobrano ".count($dostepnosc)." dostepnosci.<br>";

    $xml2 = simplexml_load_file("http://services.azymut.pl/oferta/servlet/?mode=getPrice&id=XX&p=XX") or die("Error: Cannot create object ceny");

    foreach ($xml2->book as $book)
    {
        $index = (string)$book->attributes()->indeks;
        $ceny[$index] = $book->attributes()->cena;
        $ceny[$index] = 1.30 * $ceny[$index]; //marza 30%
        $ceny[$index] = 1.05 * $ceny[$index]; //vat 5%
        $ceny[$index] = round($ceny[$index], 1);
    }

    echo "Pobrano ".count($ceny)." cen.<br>";

    for ($i = 0;$i < count($ksiazki);$i++)
    {
        $index = (string)$ksiazki[$i]->attributes()->indeks;
        //debug test
        $p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getIdBySku($index));
        echo "Usuniecie ".$p->getIdBySku($index);

        try{
            $p->delete();
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo "Delete failed";
        }


        $mediaCount = 0;
        $date = date('d/m/Y h:i:s');
        $aktualizacja = FALSE;

        if (isset($dostepnosc[$index]))
        {
            $isStock = ($dostepnosc[$index] ? 1 : 0);
        }
        else
        {
            $isStock = 0;
            $dostepnosc[$index] = 0;
        }

        if (!isset($ceny[$index]))
        {
            $ceny[$index] = 0;
        }

        echo "ID:".$product->getIdBySku($index)."<br>";
        if($product->getIdBySku($index) != NULL)
        {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getIdBySku($index));
            $mediaCount = count($product->getMediaGalleryImages());
            $date = date('d/m/Y h:i:s', strtotime($product->getCreatedAt()));

            $aktualizacja = TRUE;
            echo "Książka już istnieje, następuje nadpisywanie. Liczba obrazków książki to: ".$mediaCount.".<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            $product->setSku($index)->setIsbn($ksiazki[$i]->isbn)->setName($ksiazki[$i]->tytul)->save();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getIdBySku($index));
            echo $product->getSku()."<br>";
            echo "ID:".$product->getIdBySku($index)."<br>";
        }

        $path = dirname(__FILE__)."/media/books/".$ksiazki[$i]->attributes()->indeks.".jpeg";
        $path2 = dirname(__FILE__)."/media/books/new/".substr($product->getSku(),0,6)."i".".jpg";
        $abstract = (strlen($ksiazki[$i]->opis) > 150 ? substr($ksiazki[$i]->opis,0,150)."..." : $ksiazki[$i]->opis);
        $oprawa = 232;
        if (strpos($ksiazki[$i]->oprawa,'Miękka') !== false)
        {
            $oprawa = 233;
        }
        else
        {
            $oprawa = 232;
        }

        $redakcja = (string)$ksiazki[$i]->redakcja;

        Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

        echo $index."<br>";
        echo "Tytuł: ".$ksiazki[$i]->tytul."<br>";
        echo "ISBN: ".$ksiazki[$i]->isbn."<br>";

        $product
                    ->setStoreId(4)
                    ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
                    ->setAttributeSetId(21) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
                    ->setTypeId('simple') //product type
                    ->setCreatedAt(strtotime($date)) //product creation time
                    ->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product update time

                    ->setSku($index) //SKU
                    ->setIsbn($ksiazki[$i]->isbn)
                    ->setRok($ksiazki[$i]->rokwyd)
                    ->setOprawa($oprawa)
                    ->setStrony($ksiazki[$i]->objetosc)
                    ->setRedakcja($redakcja)
                    ->setName($ksiazki[$i]->tytul) //product name
                    ->setWeight($ksiazki[$i]->ciezar)
                    ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
                    ->setTaxClassId(11) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
                    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
                    ->setWydawnictwo($ksiazki[$i]->wydawca) //manufacturer id
                    ->setAutor($ksiazki[$i]->autorzy)
                    ->setCountryOfManufacture('PL') //country of manufacture (2-letter country code)

                    ->setPrice($ceny[$index]) //price in form 11.22
                    ->setCost(0) //price in form 11.22

                    ->setMetaTitle($ksiazki[$i]->tytul)
                    ->setMetaDescription($abstract)

                    ->setDescription($ksiazki[$i]->opis)
                    ->setShortDescription($abstract)

                    ->setPageLayout('two_columns_left')

                    ->setStockData(array(
                                       'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                                       'manage_stock'=>1, //manage stock
                                       'is_in_stock' => $isStock, //Stock Availability
                                       'qty' => $dostepnosc[$index] //qty
                                   )
                    );

                    /*
                    - pobierz ind2Cats
                    - zapisz do tab. asoc. tab[indeks] = catId
                    - stworz tab. asoc. tab[catId] = id kategorii ze strony
                    - sprawdz catId dla indeks
                    - pobierz z tab. kategorie ze strony dla catId
                    - przekaz do jako array do:
                    ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 10)); //assign product to categories
                    */

                    echo "Debug: Path - ".( (file_exists($path)) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE" )." Path2 - ".( (file_exists($path2)) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE" )." Liczba obrazkow - ".$mediaCount." Aktualizacja - ".( ($aktualizacja) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE" )."<br>";
                    if ( ( file_exists($path) || file_exists($path2) ) && $mediaCount == 0 && !$aktualizacja )
                    {
                        $finalPath = ( file_exists($path) ? $path : NULL );
                        if (!isset($finalPath))
                        {
                            $finalPath = ( file_exists($path2) ? $path : NULL );
                        }

                        if (isset($finalPath))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
                                $product->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
                                $product->addImageToMediaGallery(($finalPath), array('image','small_image','thumbnail'), false, false);
                                echo "Dodano obrazek.<br>";
                            }
                            catch(Exception $e)
                            {
                                echo "MagentoError: ".$e->getMessage();
                                Mage::log($e->getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if ($mediaCount != 0 && ( file_exists($path) || file_exists($path2) ) )
                    {
                        $mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");
                        echo $product->getId()."<br>";
                        $items = $mediaApi->items($product->getId());
                        if (count($items) > 0) { 
                            foreach($items as $item) {
                                $mediaApi->remove($product->getId(), $item['file']);
                            }
                            echo $product->getId() . " done \n";
                        } else { 
                            echo $product->getId() . " has no images \n";
                        }

                        $finalPath = ( file_exists($path) ? $path : NULL );
                        if (!isset($finalPath))
                        {
                            $finalPath = ( file_exists($path2) ? $path2 : NULL );
                        }

                        if (isset($finalPath))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                $product->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
                                $product->addImageToMediaGallery(($finalPath), array('image','small_image','thumbnail'), false, false);
                                echo "Dodano obrazek.<br>";
                            }
                            catch(Exception $e)
                            {
                                echo "MagentoError: ".$e->getMessage();
                                Mage::log($e->getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if ($aktualizacja && ( file_exists($path) || file_exists($path2) ) && $mediaCount == 0)
                    {
                        $finalPath = ( file_exists($path) ? $path : NULL );
                        if (!isset($finalPath))
                        {
                            $finalPath = ( file_exists($path2) ? $path : NULL );
                        }

                        if (isset($finalPath))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                $product->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
                                $product->addImageToMediaGallery(($finalPath), array('image','small_image','thumbnail'), false, false);
                                echo "Dodano obrazek.<br>";
                            }
                            catch(Exception $e)
                            {
                                echo "MagentoError: ".$e->getMessage();
                                Mage::log($e->getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    if (!$aktualizacja)
                    {
                        $katArray = $kat->checkForKat($index);
                        echo count($katArray)." kategorii do przypisania.<br>";
                        $product->setCategoryIds($katArray); //assign product to categories
                        $product->setNewsFromDate($date); //product set as new from
                        $dateobject = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s', $date);
                        $dateobject->modify('+1 month');
                        $product->setNewsToDate($dateobject->format('d/m/Y h:i:s')); //product set as new to
                        if (count($katArray) > 0)
                        {
                            try 
                            {
                                $product->save();
                                echo count($katArray)."Kategorii zapisano.<br>";
                                echo "Zapisano ".$ksiazki[$i]->attributes()->indeks." .<br>";
                            }
                            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                                echo $e->getMessage();
                            }
                            catch(Exception $e)
                            {
                                echo "MagentoError: ".$e->getMessage();
                                Mage::log($e->getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $product->setCategoryIds($product->getCategoryIds());
                        try 
                        {
                            $product->save();
                            echo "Nie nadpisano kategorii.<br>";
                            echo "Zapisano ".$ksiazki[$i]->attributes()->indeks." .<br>";
                        }
                        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                                echo $e->getMessage();
                        }
                        catch(Exception $e)
                        {
                            echo "MagentoError: ".$e->getMessage();
                            Mage::log($e->getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    echo $product->getSku()."<br>";
                    echo $product->getName()."<br>Koniec produktu.<br>";
    }
}

if ($i == count($ksiazki) - 1 || count($xml->books->book) == 0 || count($ksiazki == 0))
{
    //file_get_contents("http://services.azymut.pl/oferta/servlet/?mode=confirm&id=XX&p=XX&transactionId=".$transakcja) or die("Error: Cannot create object confirmation");
    echo "Koniec transakcji.<br>";
}
```

?>

Why Am I deleting the products at the beginning? It was just one of my blind shots, I wanted to start fresh, but the result was: none of the 500 products has been saved.

And here is the example of the output:

```
<code>
500 książek pobrano.
37100801579KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/37100801579KS.jpeg)
41595401615KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
41976601579KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/41976601579KS.jpeg)
42172001579KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/42172001579KS.jpeg)
43471102044KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
47354301615KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/47354301615KS.jpeg)
47359102056KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/47359102056KS.jpeg)
47495801965KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/47495801965KS.jpeg)
48445501615KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
49282501184KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
49596001579KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/49596001579KS.jpeg)
49686001350KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/49686001350KS.jpeg)
49974001615KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/49974001615KS.jpeg)
50090000207KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/50090000207KS.jpeg)
50256601579KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/50256601579KS.jpeg)
52775100231KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/52775100231KS.jpeg)
53308401041KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/53308401041KS.jpeg)
53650002269KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
54326401144KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/54326401144KS.jpeg)
55247402249KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
55250302062KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
57158801622KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/57158801622KS.jpeg)
57575602706KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/57575602706KS.jpeg)
58264602706KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/58264602706KS.jpeg)
60139002894KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/60139002894KS.jpeg)
60143302894KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/60143302894KS.jpeg)
60159902894KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/60159902894KS.jpeg)
60160802894KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/60160802894KS.jpeg)
60161202894KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
61274601830KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
61829501075KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
61977702706KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
62104401430KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/62104401430KS.jpeg)
63614801262KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
64253303114KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
64894500149KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
65196601622KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
65392002743KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
66167802894KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
66338102894KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
66690002894KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
66988102894KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
67454302494KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
67848500153KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/67848500153KS.jpeg)
68804402044KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/68804402044KS.jpeg)
70217100206KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
70217400206KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
70227603326KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/70227603326KS.jpeg)
70341400124KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/70341400124KS.jpeg)
70360802389KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/70360802389KS.jpeg)
70362502608KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/70362502608KS.jpeg)
70486401049KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/70486401049KS.jpeg)
70491003053KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/70491003053KS.jpeg)
70491203053KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
70526003143KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/70526003143KS.jpeg)
70526701252KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
70530302894KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
70550401646KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
70551601405KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
70557401144KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
70559601648KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/70559601648KS.jpeg)
70649402608KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
70658902608KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
70662201184KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
70682202798KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
70685101549KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
70689500208KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/70689500208KS.jpeg)
70693701252KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
70695103053KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
70719900208KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/70719900208KS.jpeg)
70720100208KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
70720200208KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/70720200208KS.jpeg)
70720400208KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/70720400208KS.jpeg)
70740003022KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/70740003022KS.jpeg)
70744600203KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/70744600203KS.jpeg)
70753403053KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/70753403053KS.jpeg)
70755102370KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/70755102370KS.jpeg)
70755302370KS: Pobrano obrazek.(/media/books/70755302370KS.jpeg)
70761603133KS: Brak obrazka w bazie Azymuta.
Transakcja 11145-1424312459597
Pobrano 107534 dostepnosci.
Pobrano 134930 cen.
Usuniecie 4243ID:
37100801579KS
ID:29376
37100801579KS
Tytuł: MW
ISBN: 839176124X
Debug: Path - TRUE Path2 - TRUE Liczba obrazkow - 0 Aktualizacja - FALSE
Dodano obrazek.
2 kategorii do przypisania.
2Kategorii zapisano.
Zapisano 37100801579KS .
37100801579KS
MW
Koniec produktu.
Usuniecie 4906ID:
41595401615KS
ID:29376
41595401615KS
Tytuł: Historia polityczna świata XX w t1 1901-1945
ISBN: 8323318522
Debug: Path - FALSE Path2 - TRUE Liczba obrazkow - 0 Aktualizacja - FALSE
MagentoError: Image does not exist.7 kategorii do przypisania.
7Kategorii zapisano.
Zapisano 41595401615KS .
41595401615KS
Historia polityczna świata XX w t1 1901-1945
Koniec produktu.
Usuniecie 4974ID:
41976601579KS
ID:29376
41976601579KS
Tytuł: Salon 2. Alfabet szulerów. Część pierwsza A-L
ISBN: 8360297118
Debug: Path - TRUE Path2 - TRUE Liczba obrazkow - 0 Aktualizacja - FALSE
Dodano obrazek.
3 kategorii do przypisania.
3Kategorii zapisano.
Zapisano 41976601579KS .
41976601579KS
Salon 2. Alfabet szulerów. Część pierwsza A-L
Koniec produktu.
Usuniecie 2240ID:
42172001579KS
ID:29376
42172001579KS
Tytuł: Salon 2 Alfabet szulerów
ISBN: 8360297126
Debug: Path - TRUE Path2 - TRUE Liczba obrazkow - 0 Aktualizacja - FALSE
Dodano obrazek.
3 kategorii do przypisania.
3Kategorii zapisano.
Zapisano 42172001579KS .
42172001579KS
Salon 2 Alfabet szulerów
Koniec produktu.
Usuniecie 5376ID:
43471102044KS
ID:29376
43471102044KS
Tytuł: Tajemnica Las Meninas
ISBN: 9788389368737
Debug: Path - FALSE Path2 - TRUE Liczba obrazkow - 0 Aktualizacja - FALSE
MagentoError: Image does not exist.2 kategorii do przypisania.
2Kategorii zapisano.
Zapisano 43471102044KS .
43471102044KS
Tajemnica Las Meninas
Koniec produktu.
Koniec transakcji.
</code>
```

Comment: Do you have a store with id 4 in your site?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work on any ID and even if I comment this line. Note one weird fact: every "saved" object in this example output has exactly the same ID. I dont know why. It's this line for example:
41976601579KS
ID:29376 <- this is the ID of every product and it's the same!
41976601579KS

Answer (score 1):

I can't run this since I don't have your XML or the rest of your code but based on what you've described as your problem one thing stands out to me.

Starting here:

```
    echo "ID:".$product->getIdBySku($index)."<br>";

//// I get this part because you're loading your existing product.

    if($product->getIdBySku($index) != NULL)
    {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getIdBySku($index));
        $mediaCount = count($product->getMediaGalleryImages());
        $date = date('d/m/Y h:i:s', strtotime($product->getCreatedAt()));

        $aktualizacja = TRUE;
        echo "Książka już istnieje, następuje nadpisywanie. Liczba obrazków książki to: ".$mediaCount.".<br>";

    }
    else
    {

//// This part is redundant. You're doing this again below after this section.

        $product->setSku($index)->setIsbn($ksiazki[$i]->isbn)->setName($ksiazki[$i]->tytul)->save();
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getIdBySku($index));
        echo $product->getSku()."<br>";
        echo "ID:".$product->getIdBySku($index)."<br>";
    }
```

Try replacing the code above with this:

```
    echo "ID:".$product->getIdBySku($index)."<br>";

    if($product->getIdBySku($index) != NULL)
    {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getIdBySku($index));
        $mediaCount = count($product->getMediaGalleryImages());
        $date = date('d/m/Y h:i:s', strtotime($product->getCreatedAt()));

        $aktualizacja = TRUE;
        echo "Książka już istnieje, następuje nadpisywanie. Liczba obrazków książki to: ".$mediaCount.".<br>";

    }
    else
    {

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

    }
```

Comment: It looks like it worked, the product has been added. That's funny because this "else" was added when I tried to figure this problem out, before I posted here. : D Anyway, there is one problem now, the photos are loaded into the product, but they are not "checked" as base, small and thumbnail. Strange.

Comment: Oh, no I have examined this further and the products are saved, but they are mixed up? When I look for SKU of one book in magento backend, there is completly another book with that SKU.

Comment: You do need that `else`.  If not then it will save incorrectly.  Try re-adding it exactly how I had it in my answer.

Comment: Still some of the products are mixed up, what I mean is: there are a few exactly identical products, but with a different SKU, although they were saved as 2 different products (I'm sure, because I echo all the essential values during the process). Also the images are saved, but they are not "checked" as base image, small image and thumbnail - the effect is they have no image in the frontend.